# Is it allowed to run several different DHT nodes behind the same ip:port pair in Mainline DHT?

Tags: bittorrent, dht

Is it allowed to run several different DHT nodes behind the same ip:port pair in Mainline DHT?
And which node should reply on the DHT query message?
All or one of them?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is: one of them. Each request is expected to yield a single response.

DHT nodes are assumed to have a persistent node-ID associated with their (IP, port)-pair. If the node ID changes (or as you phrase it, a different node responds) its entry in the remote node's routing table is likely to be removed and replaced by the new node ID.

It is probably a better idea to run the nodes on different ports, so that requests to the same port results in responses from the same node with the same node-ID.

As a side note, the Azureus has certain security features in its DHT to mitigate attacks that where an attacker owns a certain area of the node ID space by restricting which node IDs you can run on any given IP address. There is a proposal to do something similar for the mainline DHT (proposed by me) [DHT security extension](http://www.rasterbar.com/products/libtorrent/dht_sec.html). With something like this deployed, you would be limited in how many nodes you could run behind a single IP address.